# string index out of range in inverted index implementation

Tags: python, string

*********************file a.py*********************************

```
a=input()
while (not  (a[len(a)-1].isalpha())):
    a=a[:-1]
print(a)
```

*****************part of  file b.py*********************************

```
for my_word in my_words.split():  
    while(not(my_word[len(my_word)-1].isalpha())):  
        my_word=my_word[:-1]  
    ll=lemmatizer.lemmatize(my_word.lower())  
    if ll not in stop_words:  
        l.append(ll)
```

---

file a.py runs fine but b.py gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 42, in <module>
    while(not(my_word[len(my_word)-1].isalpha())):
IndexError: string index out of range.
```

If I remove the while loop

```
while(not(my_word[len(my_word)-1].isalpha())):  
            my_word=my_word[:-1]
```

my code(b.py) runs fine. But I want to remove special characters suffixes from my word.

Comment: If `my_word` does not have any alphabetic symbols, it is shrunk in the `for` loop to an empty string. The length of an empty string is 0, so `my_word[len(my_word)-1]` becomes `my_word[-1]`, but since an empty string does not have any characters (even the last one), you get an index error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression substitution (instead of the `while` loop) to remove non-alphabetic characters:

```
import re
my_word = "Hello_world+?a123"
re.sub(r"(\W|\d|_)+", "", my_word)
#'Helloworlda'
```